# No tengo conexión a red ni dirección ipv4 en mi virtual box de parrot

Tags: virtualbox, ip, internet

al ejecutar mi máquina virtual con la red en modo adaptador puente no obtengo ni conexión a internet ni tampoco dirección IP, he comprobado el servidor DHCP y está activo, no se qué puede fallar. En cambio con una conexión NAT si que obtengo conexión a internet.

Comment: Para que funcione la conexión a internet en modo puente necesitas usar otro adaptador de red.